# OS X Serial Number in VM

Tags: macos, virtualization, osx-mountain-lion, serial

I was wondering after installation of Mountain Lion on VMWare or other virtualization softwares (on a mac) will it show the same "serial number" in "About This Mac"? And is it possible to customize that serial number, for development and test? And if it's possible, is it legal? (I know changing "Hardware UUID" is possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial number isn't related to the OS at all. It's part of the hardware of your Mac, and actually it should be printed in/on the machine somewhere (depends on  the model of course.)

If you install OS X in a virtual machine, the serial number will have to be faked. For example, a non-official x86 version of OS X uses "W1234567980". Others may use different numbers, none of which are real, of course.

Installing OS X in a virtual machine is [against the EULA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX108.pdf), except for old versions of OS X Server and OS X Mountain Lion, the latter of which may only be virtualized on Apple computers running OS X 10.8 themselves:

> … install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software 
>   within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is 
>   already running the Apple Software, for purposes of: (a) software development; (b) testing 
>   during software development; (c) using OS X Server; or (d) personal, non-commercial use